# How to get LyX to regenerate an entire LaTeX -> PDF document when I change the .bib file?

Tags: bibliographies, lyx, auxiliary-files

According to [an earlier discussion](http://How%20can%20I%20force%20LyX%20to%20rebuild%20intermediate%20files%20for%20clean%20PDF%20display?) LyX only updates all the intermediate LaTeX files when certain kinds of errors are reported in the log. I assume it also regenerates the files when the document in LyX changes.

But I'm just making changes to the references in a .bib file, and LyX seems to do nothing when I do. It appears the only way I can see the changes in a final document is by restarting LyX, and I'm not even sure this always will work.

Can someone shed more light on this problem?

Comment: I don't know Lyx, but in general for LaTeX, modifying the `bib` file requires the `.bbl` file to be deleted, so that it can be regenerated anew.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes You don't have to delete the `.bbl` file though, do you? You'd just run `bibtex` again. The problem here is that LyX uses something akin to Latexmk, and when deciding whether or not to run BibTeX, it doesn't check the `.bib` file for changes, only the document itself.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. With TeXworks, I don't know how to invoke just `bibtex`.  So instead, I delete the `bbl` and recompile with `pdflatex`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes You select BibTeX in the dropdown menu on the toolbar (where it says pdfLaTeX, or pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX by default), then hit Ctrl + T or click the green arrow. (Gnosos, sorry for the off-topic talk.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I am so embarrassed.  I never scrolled down the menu far enough to see that option (sheepish grin).

Comment: Gnosos, I just tried, and I can't actually replicate the behaviour you describe. I made a new file, added a bibliography, and just a single citation. I edited the `.bib` file without making any changes in the `.lyx` file, and when updating the PDF the reference updates as well. For reference, I have version 2.1.4 of LyX, running Kubuntu. The newest version is 2.2.1.

Comment: It works for me on LyX + Ubuntu also with 2.2.1.